# Почему не могу создать таблицу через PGAdmin4?

Tags: postgresql

подустал уже от этого нового pgadmin4. Ничего в нем не работает. Сейчас пытался создать таблицу и то не смог. Кто-нибудь знает что это такое?

attribute 'encoding' of 'psycopg2.extensions.QuotedString' objects is not writable

Саму БД через докер устанавливал
PostgreSQL 9.6.8 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Debian 9.6.8-1.pgdg80+1), compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10+deb8u1) 4.9.2, 64-bit

pgadmin4 из репозитория Ubuntu
Version2.1
CopyrightCopyright 2013 - 2018, The pgAdmin Development Team
Python Version3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
Flask Version0.10.1
Application ModeDesktop
Current Userpgadmin4@pgadmin.org

Comment: Это проблема явно с pgAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Если закомментировать эти две строчки в /usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/utils/driver/psycopg2/__init__.py, ошибка исчезает:

```
   if hasattr(adapted, 'encoding'):
       adapted.encoding = 'utf8'
```